# Replace In Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running a `asp.net` app and am capturing a date in a text field.  I now want to strip the "\" from that field

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox does not contain a definition for 'Replace'

Updating to the below syntax produces these compile errors:

> Newline in constant
>   ) expected
>   ; expected

```
string noseperator = this.txtdate1.Text.Replace("\", "");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the property `Text` to get the value of the textfield:

```
string noseperator = this.txtdate1.Text.Replace("\\", "");
```

The backslash "\" character is an escape character used to indicate other ones.
So in your example you need a double backslash to get it working.

Comment: that got it.  What causes it to need a double-quote?